# Question related to Wald and Wolfowitz paper on tolerance limits

Tags: normal-distribution, tolerance-interval

I have a question regarding Wald and Wolfowitz paper on tolerance limits for a normal distribution. There paper can be found
[here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730981)

Wald and Wolfowitz denote the root of the equation: $ A(\bar{x},s,\lambda) = \gamma $, as $s=r(\bar{x},\gamma, \lambda)$, before they state that $r(\bar{x},\gamma, \lambda) = \frac{r(\bar{x},\gamma)}{\lambda}$.

I wonder how it is possible to see this; i.e that $\lambda$ can be factorized out from the expression for r. Is there a connection to the derivative of $ A(\bar{x},s,\lambda) $ given as:
$\frac{d}{ds}A(\bar{x},s,\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\bar{x}}\left(e^{\frac{1}{2}\lambda s}+e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda s} \right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\lambda e^{-\frac{1}{2}\bar{x}} cosh(\frac{1}{2}\lambda s) >0$

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to assume that the equation: $ A(\bar{x},s,\lambda) = \gamma $ can be solved analytical (despite that it cannot) w.r.t $s$, and since $\lambda$ and $s$ follows each other everywhere (they are a product) you will get something like this after some hypothetical operations like factorizations etc: $$\lambda s = r(\bar{x},\gamma)$$

From this the result follows: $s = \frac{r(\bar{x},\gamma)}{\lambda}  $.

But please, correct me if I am totally of

[image]